# Convergence of two sequences imply convergence of a third

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the following sequences:
$$a_{n} \searrow_{\ n} 0,\;\;\;k_n\leq n,\;\;\;k_n\to+\infty,\;\;\;\;b_n=\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}\frac{1}{\min(a_{i-1}-a_i,a_i-a_{i+1})},$$
and I want to prove that
$$\frac{\log(n)}{a_{k_n}^4n}\to0,\;\; \frac{\log(n)b_n^2}{n\cdot a_{k_n}^2}\to0 \implies \frac{\log(n)b_n}{n\cdot a_{k_n}^3}\to0$$

**My attempt**:

I tried using Sandwich's rule, and so I have to prove that
$$\frac{1}{a_{k_n}^2} \leq \frac{b_n}{a_{k_n}}\leq b_n^2\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{1}{a_{k_n}^2} \geq \frac{b_n}{a_{k_n}}\geq b_n^2$$
if we were to follow this way we could consider $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ then $\min(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}) = \min(\frac{1}{n(n-1)},\frac{1}{n(n+1)})=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ and see that.
$$n^2=\frac{1}{a_{k_n}^2}\leq n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)=n\cdot\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)=n^2\left(\frac{2(n+1)(2n+1)-6(n-1)}{12}\right)$$ if $n$ is large enough. So if the statement were correct, the first road should be the right one. However, I don't know any good bounds to try to formally prove it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_n = \frac{\log(n)}{a_{k_n}^4 n}$,
$d_n = \frac{\log(n)b_n^2}{a_{k_n}^2 n}$.
Then you only need to observe that the third sequence is $\sqrt{c_n d_n}$ and
$$\min(c_n, d_n) \leq \sqrt{c_n d_n} \leq \max(c_n, d_n).$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hahahaha it was much simpler than I had thought, thank you, hadn't thought of that at all.